# swfupload jquery plugin file upload list

Tags: jquery, swfupload

Was just wondering if anyone knows if you can set the limit of upload files to display on the list after selecting the files? (**NOT** the max amount of images you can upload)

eg. I choose to upload 10 images, normally it will display a list with all 10 images in the queue... instead i want it to display only 5 images and as each uploads and leaves the queue list at the bottom the next one shows up...

**OR**

another option is to display the overall upload progress instead of individual files... is this possible with this plugin?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

You might be having code like this

```
jQuery('#swfupload-control').swfupload({
    upload_url: "progress/upload-file.php?uid="+uid,
    file_post_name: 'uploadfile',
    file_size_limit : "25600",
    file_types : "*.mpeg;*.flv;*.mp4;*.mpg;*.wmv;*.3gp;",
    file_types_description : "Video files",
    file_upload_limit : 10000,
    flash_url : "progress/js/swfupload/swfupload.swf",
    button_image_url : 'progress/js/swfupload/upload_btn.png',
    button_width : 74,
    button_height : 23,
    button_placeholder : jQuery('#button')[0],
    debug: false
})
```

In that change value of this attribute to 5

```
file_upload_limit : 5,
```

with regards
Wasim

Comment: i believe i may have found what im looking for however I am not home to test this. The setting is: "file_queue_limit: 5" the upload limit will restrict the user to only be able to select 5 files for upload however i want to be able to select more.

Comment: I just got home and tried both out apperently the file_upload_limit sets the maximum upload amount of files a user can upload while the queue sets the maximum amount of files a user can upload at once... Neither of these complete the function im looking for unfortunately... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well found one solution to this issue adding a **max-height** to the css file and **overflow: auto** this way atleast it doesnt grow when theres alot of files in the queue list just has a scrollbar. The other two options i was looking for I still havent found a solution to. If anyone knows these ways or any other way please share!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can do one thing

Make your height of the division such that it can only show 10 uploads

Add some attribute `id` to `var listitem='<li id="'+file.id+'" >'+`

In

```
.bind('uploadSuccess', function(event, file, serverData){
    //instead use $("#"+file.id).remove() to remove the list item which got completed
    item.addClass('success').find('p.status').html();
})
```